# LaTeX fonts for NSF Proposals

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I'd like to use LaTeX to format an NSF proposal, but am nervous about the differences in fonts between standard LaTeX tools and the NSF Guidelines.  The guidelines state:

> Use one of the following typefaces identified below: Arial, Courier
>   New, or Palatino Linotype at a font size of 10 points or larger Times
>   New Roman at a font size of 11 points or larger; or Computer Modern
>   family of fonts at a font size of 11 points or larger.

Does anybody know how these constraints translate for purposes of LaTeX formatting?  In particular, I'd like to know what range of typesetting options are permissible for meeting their page requirements.

Comment: Use `XeTeX` engine: it allows to use system-wide fonts, like Times, Arial etc.

Comment: The default font for LaTeX is Computer Modern.  To get the point size, specify either `\documenclass[11pt]{<classname>}` or `\documentclass[12pt]{<classname>}`.

Comment: I believe those guidelines were actually modified in part due to outrage over the first version which was almost impossible to adhere to in TeX. As A.Ellett said, CM is default. To make sure you get outline (not bitmap) fonts, use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in your preamble. Provided you have a reasonably sane installation, this will get you type 1 versions of the CM fonts which is almost certainly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully NSF proposal guidelines are quite minimal. I use  `article` class with `geometry` to set the margins and `titlesec` to make all the headings smaller. . I do use XeLaTeX though, to avoid any issue with fonts. Since Fastlane has extensive PDF generation and checking facilities it might actually be able to check for fonts, but I've never tried.

Answer (score 3):

Computer Modern comes with every TeX distribution under the sun. That said, would they really reject a proposal because it was formatted in [Helvetica](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/helvet) (which most people wouldn't be able to tell from Arial anyway) or URW Palladio (A Palatino clone)?

Comment: URW Palladio *is* Palatino by none but Zapf himself, it id not a clone.

Comment: Sadly, yes, grant proposals get rejected on the flimsiest of technical details even before they reach the reviewing stage.